# Extend x-axis beyond xrange in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, axis

I am trying to draw a larger x-axis than my xrange.
I.e. my xrange is [0:10]
I plot f(x)=sin(x)
But I want the x-scale to be from 0 to 15

xtics doesn't solve this problem as it will not extent beyond the set xrange.

jlinkels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can simply be done using `set offsets`:

```
set xrange [0:10]
set offsets 0,5,0,0
plot sin(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Never seen that command before, but that's it. Thanks very much.